# redirect to routes that has the same url in multiple apps

Tags: python, django, redirect, routes, django-urls

I'm new to coding so excuse me if this was a silly question but I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere.
So I have a django project with two apps inside it, both of them has the root '/',what is the exact format and implementation to use return redirect('/')to let django differentiate between these two roots in different apps maybe using naming routes.
a step by step guide will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you have a django project called **InitialProject** and the project has 2 apps inside, let's call them **MyApp1** and **MyApp2**.

Your directory structure should look something like this:

```
PythonProject/
├─ InitialProject/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ asgi.py
│  ├─ settings.py
│  ├─ urls.py
│  ├─ wsgi.py
├─ MyApp1/
│  ├─ migrations/
│  ├─ filters.py
│  ├─ tests.py
│  ├─ urls.py
│  ├─ views.py
│  ├─ models.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ admin.py
│  ├─ apps.py
├─ MyApp2/
│  ├─ migrations/
│  ├─ filters.py
│  ├─ tests.py
│  ├─ urls.py
│  ├─ views.py
│  ├─ models.py
│  ├─ admin.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ apps.py
```

So firstly, URLs are unique, that is 1 URL can only lead to one path or one views function in this case. But what we can do is that we can say that URL starting with **'APP1'** should look into **MyApp1/urls.py** for the function and URL starting with **'APP2'** should look into **MyApp2/urls.py**

So in **InitialProject/urls.py**, we define it as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('APP1/', include('MyApp1.urls')), # Note the trailing forward slash, it is important
    path('APP2/', include('MyApp2.urls')),
]
```

So, what this does is that is:
if your URL is: HTTP://localhost/APP1/
it will tell Django to look into MyApp1/urls.py to resolve and get the function and similarly for APP2.

Now in MyApp1/urls.py we can do is that:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.my_function_1),  # This URL will resolve as HTTP://localhost/APP1/
    path('second_url', views.my_function_2), # This URL will resolve as HTTP://localhost/APP1/second_url
]
```

And similarly can be done for **MyApp2**. By this method, you have a cleaner URL structure and it is also easy to navigate and see which app is being called.

I hope you are able to understand how URL Patterns work.

You might as why did we define the initial URL pattern in **InitialProject/urls.py**? Because by default Django will first go to the project directory to see which URL patterns and from there only we can link other App's URL patterns.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation